# Preprocessor directive inside an one line if

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I have this function

```
TOKENP scan_line() {
    TOKENP cur, last = 0;

    while(cur = scan_opd())
        last = cur;

    if (cur = scan_comm())
    #if ENABLE_COMMENT_AS_TOKEN
        add_token(cur);
    #endif
    return last;
}
```

If the `#if` directive is false, will it be compiled as

```
if (cur = scan_comm())
    return last;
```

or

```
if (cur = scan_comm());
return last;
```

?

Comment: Your return will become conditional.

Comment: a) Why would the #if directive being false magically insert a semicolon? b) RTFM. It takes less effort for everyone and you learn everything at once instead of piecemeal. c) If the #if directive is false, your colleagues will string you up for writing code like that.

Comment: @Fabricio - He's saying they'd string you up for it since that's going to cause a logic error that's damn hard to track down at best.

Comment: @JimBalter - No offence meant. I just found your RTFM amusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be compiled just as if the disabled line didn't exist, so:

```
if (cur = scan_comm())
    return last;
```

You should use braces to make it clear what you mean.

```
if (cur = scan_comm())
{
    #if ENABLE_COMMENT_AS_TOKEN
    add_token(cur);
    #endif
}    
return last;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will compile out that code, so your return statement will become conditional. Meaning:

```
if(cur = scan_comm())
  return last;
```

Graham Borland, got this right, but I want to make sure it was clear to you what the problem is. Take a look at this:

```
int somef(int a)
{
    if(a == 0)
#if something
    a++; 
#endif
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 10;

    b = somef(a); 

    printf("b is %d\n", b);
    ...do more useful stuff with b...
```

If you compile this code with `gcc -Werror -Wall` it should fail, with something like "control reaches end of non-void function". This is letting you know there's a problem with the code.

If you compile without the safety options it might go through without even a warning. Now you think everything's fine, but since in this sample code `something` is not defined, that code is gone and we don't get "0" back from the function call. In this specific case b was assigned 3.

We've gone into some undefined behavior here. Now when I'm doing "useful stuff" with b, expecting it was originally 0, I'm going to have a **very** hard time understanding why the value was "3".

It's always safe to have brackets:

```
if (cur = scan_comm())
    add_token(cur);

return last;
```

vs.

```
if (cur = scan_comm())
{
    add_token(cur);
}

return last;
```

Both of these work the same, but the second helps protect against stupid mistakes.